# Mount a new volume into a docker instance

Tags: linux, docker, mount

I have a web site running in a docker instance.  The site has a documents folder that needs more storage.  So, I created a new volume on AWS.  I can see it from the host with `lsblk`, like so:

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  20G  0 disk
```

Within the web site structure, inside the docker container, I would like to mount the disk to:

```
/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents/
```

Normally, I would just use the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents/
```

But since it is in a docker container, I'm a bit confused on how to connect it.  **How can I mount the drive to the given directory?**

Docker is quite new to me. I barely heard of it until a few weeks ago. I have control to `sh` into the container and also restart it.

Comment: @A.B - OK. I'm kind of starting to get it.  I have a docker-compose.yml file, I tried adding:    - /mnt/documents:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents under volumes, but didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, figured it out.

First, I had to track down how the instance was started in the first place.  By this command:

```
./docker-compose up -d --build
```

In that same directory, there was a docker-compose.yml file, so I added the following line, in the main service ( and not top level):

```
- /mnt:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents
```

Stopped the instance
Mounted the drive:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt
```

Restarted the container:

```
./docker-compose up -d --build
```

shelled into the docker instance, and verified volume mounted with:

```
df
```

Comment: If it is your question answered, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question for more information on the different mount types in Docker: [What is the difference between creating a volume or a mount in docker containers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/854562/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-a-volume-or-a-mount-in-docker-containers)

You need to moun the volume first to a local folder on your 'host' server and then you can mount it to your docker container.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Read through that question and the answers.  Still confused.  So, I mount the volume to host system. fine. Then how to connect the directory to docker?

Answer (score 4):

First mount the device to directory:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt
```

Then you have to start container with parameter, which connects your volume (directory) to container directory:

```
docker run -d \
 --name devtest \
 -v /mnt:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents \
 nginx:latest
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount

Or with docker-compose.yml:

```
devtest:
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
    - /mnt:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents
```

Comment: This looks promising.  But I have an existing instance that I been using 'docker restart' as needed. How would I go about adding this to an existing container?  Also, it Apache based.

Comment: I have a docker-compose.yml file, but I don't seem to have volumes syntax down correctly.  Any insights?

Comment: try similar:
    volumes:
     - /mnt:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/sites/default/documents